# Liquid - Conditionally Include File From _includes Folder

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a default.html file in _layout folder. This file contains elements that are common throughout the entire site (e.g., the `<head>` element), and is supposed to be called in other layout files, which will further extend it.

Depending on the file that calls default.html, I want to include the appropriate snippets in the `<head>` element.

For instance, consider the (simplified) example files bellow:

_includes/post_metadata.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="post.css">
```

_layouts/default.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    {% if <is_post_layout> %}
      {% include post_metadata.html %}
    {% endif %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

_layouts/post_layout.html

```
---
layout: default
---
<article>
  {{ content }}
</article>
```

_posts/2021-09-22-post.md:

```
---
layout: post_layout
---
[...]
```

The final page generated by Jekyll should contain:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="post.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <article>
      [...]
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, what code should I use to replace <is_post_layout> to make it work?

Comment: Are you still working on this? I'm not sure from your question what you're after. My best guess is `{% if page.layout == 'post_layout' %}`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two (and even more) options.

One is similar to the comment of @`Brad West`.

You can create many layouts, see [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/layouts/). So create a post.html (e.g. based on default.html) layout and place it inside `_layouts` folder. Then you can use the layout in the front matter block. For layouts from scratch can use `none` for an empty layout.

Use a `default` layout

```markdown
---
layout: default
---
```

Use a `post` layout

```markdown
---
layout: post
---
```

The `_layouts/default.html`

```html
<html>
  <body>
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

The `_layouts/post.html`

```html
---
layout: none
---
<html>
  <head>
    {% include post_metadata.html %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

The other one is do it with a variable `include_post_metadata` in the front matter block. Set the variable to true, when it will be omit then it is false / nil, and the if condition will be not excuted.

```markdown
---
layout: default
include_post_metadata: true
---
```

The `_layouts/default.html`

```html
<html>
  <head>
    {% if page.include_post_metadata %}
      {% include post_metadata.html %}
    {% endif %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

> Page (`page.include_post_metadata`) is valid for pages and posts